# Дело пахнет керосином

Tags: фразеология

Интересно, откуда пошла эта поговорка как синоним провала дела?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта фраза из фельетона «Всё в порядке» (Правда. 1924. 22 апр.) известного советского журналиста 1920-х гг. Михаила Ефимовича Кольцова (псевдоним М. Е. Фридлянда, 1898—1940). Он написал о крупной афере с концессиями на добычу нефти в штате Калифорния (США), в которой, как показало расследование, оказались замешаны высокопоставленные американские чиновники, что заставило скомпрометированного министра юстиции США уйти в отставку (об этом «Правда» сообщила 30 марта 1924 г.). 
В фельетоне М. Е. Кольцов писал: «Американцы подозрительно потянули носом: из Белого дома явственно попахивало чем-то горючим. Нефть — не нефть, а что-то вроде очищенного бензина чувствует- 
127). Его строка из 14-й сатиры была очень популярной в Риме: Lucri bonus est odor ex re qualibet (лукри бонус эст одор экс рэ квалибэт) — Запах прибыли хорош, каково бы ни было ее происхождение. 
Крылатое выражение «деньги не пахнут» есть краткая, прозаическая версия этой поэтической строчки. 
Иносказательно: важно наличие денег, а не источник их происхождения (ирон.).
А обозначает эта фраза следующее: до беды недалеко, долго ли до беды?, опасно, пахнет жареным, пахнет порохом, попахивает неприятностями, рискованно.